# How to make a delete route with Express API

Tags: typescript, express, mean-stack

I am trying to delete records from mongodb with an API using MEAN-stack. my application sucessfully calls the API but the API does not delete anything. I'm using a get request because 'del' or 'delete' causes even more trouble.

application (typescript):

```
DeleteSurvey(){
    var obj = this.surveys[this.listnames.indexOf(this.ListId)];

    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/surveys/{"id":"' + obj._id + '"}').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

API:

```
router.get('/surveys/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const id = JSON.parse(req.params.id);
    console.log(id);
    const message = await Survey
     .findByIdAndRemove(id)
     .then(() => 'Survey deleted');
     res.json(message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says that if you pass a callback on `findByIdAndRemove` it will execute the query.

```
Survey.findByIdAndRemove(id, options, callback) // executes
Survey.findByIdAndRemove(id, options)  // return Query
Survey.findByIdAndRemove(id, callback) // executes
Survey.findByIdAndRemove(id) // returns Query
Survey.findByIdAndRemove()           // returns Query
```

It does not do anything because you are not passing any callback. So in your case you should do.

```
Survey.findByIdAndRemove(id,(err, doc)=> res.send(' 
Successfully deleted'))
```